# Sorting/Paging/Filtering callback action parameters are empty using Custom Data Binding with DevExpress MVC GridVIew extension

Tags: asp.net-mvc, gridview, devexpress-mvc

I'm trying to get the DevExpress grid view extension working using *custom data binding* with an existing ASP.NET MVC 3 site.  I've read through and followed [the steps in this guide in the DevExpress documentation](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument14374), but when I try to page, sort or filter, the column information in the `GridViewPagerState` or `GridViewColumnState` objects that are bound to the callbacks used to handle these operations come back with default (blank) column information.

I can run the "simple custom data binding" and "advanced custom data binding" demos from the demo center application - these both work as expected.  When I transplant the code into my application though, it doesn't work.

How can I get past this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I was missing the setup of the `DevExpressEditorsBinder` in my *Global.asax.cs* file.  Unfortunately I skimmed over this highlighted note taken from the [Custom Data Binding - Overview](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument14374):

> **Note**
>   When implementing the grid's custom data binding, the [`DevExpressEditorsBinder`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/clsDevExpressWebMvcDevExpressEditorsBindertopic) must be used instead of the default model binder to correctly transfer values from DevExpress editors back to the corresponding data model fields. See the **Binding to Model** section in the [Binding Data Editors to Data](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument11784) topic for more details on how to specify `DevExpressEditorsBinder` as a model binder.